# How convert Object Array to a single Array

Tags: javascript

I have this obj array

```
0: "aab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e41"
1: "beb9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e62"
2: "a2b9953c0f0493808331c2da42050e51"
3: "2ab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e4a"
```

What is the best method to join all of them on a single array ?

**Expected Result**

```
["aab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e41","beb9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e62","a2b9953c0f0493808331c2da42050e51","2ab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e4a"]
```

Comment: where is that first value coming from?

Comment: plese provide a [mcve]

Comment: from a obj called 'parts'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be sure to preserve the order, you can give the object a `length` attribute and use `Array.from()`:

```js
let obj = {
0: "aab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e41",
1: "beb9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e62",
2: "a2b9953c0f0493808331c2da42050e51",
3: "2ab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e4a"
}
obj.length = Object.values(obj).length

let arr = Array.from(obj)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of _preserve the order_ here?

Comment: @rv7 I mean the resulting array will be in sequential order of the keys of the object.

Comment: I wanted to suggest `Array.from` as well but forgot how to make an object iterable. A very elegant answer, cool! BTW do you have a link to the reference about adding a `length` property?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let obj  = 
{0: "aab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e41",
1: "beb9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e62",
2: "a2b9953c0f0493808331c2da42050e51",
3: "2ab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e4a"}
console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Comment: note that his will be in value inserted order only.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the data maters, you can create a custom map-sort-map function.

```js
const Sorters = {
  sortBy                       : (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b),
  sortByKeyAsString            : (a, b) => a.key.toString().localeCompare(b.key.toString()),
  sortByKeyAsInteger           : (a, b) => a.key - b.key,
  sortByKeyAsIntegerFromString : (a, b) => parseInt(a.key, 10) - parseInt(b.key, 10),
  sortByValueAsString          : (a, b) => a.value.toString().localeCompare(b.value.toString()),
  sortByValueAsInteger         : (a, b) => a.value - b.value
};

function toOrderedArray(obj, sorterFn) {
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .map(key => ({ key : key, value : obj[key] }))
    .sort(sorterFn || Sorters.sortByKeyAsString)
    .map(item => item.value);
}

let data = {
  0: "aab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e41",
  1: "beb9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e62",
  2: "a2b9953c0f0493808331c2da42050e51",
  3: "2ab9d17c0f0493808331c2da42050e4a"
};

console.log(toOrderedArray(data, Sorters.sortByKeyAsInteger));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```